# SUP101: blackberry works on simulator but not device

Tags: blackberry, device, sup

I'm having a problem with getting the tutorial to work on the device

it works fine in the simulator, but when I try to run it on the device it doesn't work.

I put some logs and it seems to come from the login function

```
===JASONROGERS292C 2480 supAdmin s3pAdmin
[0.0] TAC:TAI.handleRegRsp : ALREADY_REGISTERED
[0.0] TAC:TAI.handleRegRsp : (ALREADY_REGISTERED), registered entry found:{{APN=,id=2,state=CLOSED,waf=WAF[0.0] _3GPP,keepAlive=300,IP=0.0.0.0,dnsSrv=0.0.0.0}}
[0.0] [TMM.TunnelAllocator]:runNotReadyListeners: registered listeners found
[0.0] TAC:TAI.handleListenerDeRegRsp: not existent tunnel in TAC, tid=2
[0.0] SIM cache not loaded
```

has anybody got an idea what I forgot to do when running the code on a device?

Cheers 
Jason

---

edit:

a couple of links towards what I'm doing (I can post all the code people want but its the standard generated code form SUP, which mean a lot of code lol)

The tutorial
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01214.0200/doc/html/title.html

the zip to the already done tutorial :
http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/bpx/index?rid=/webcontent/uuid/40ea4956-b95c-2e10-11b3-e68c73b2280e

---

Solution: 
I was missing a couple of things:
1) Specify that the app should use Wifi

```
SUP101DB.getSynchronizationProfile().setString("transport", "WIFI");
```

2) Check that the DNS: in my case the server was local to my windows (through parallels) so I had to specify the ip and not the namespace

```
getSynchronizationProfile().setServerName("10.50.30.108");//"JASONSERVER");
```

Comment: From the logs it looks like this is related to networking (a tricky part of BB development). Is the code that makes HTTP requests available for you? If yes, then it would be better to post it so we could study what could be wrong.

Comment: its network related but its what SUP generates for you (it generate codes that handles all the communication with the server for you). I'll add a couple of links but since its not my code and that SUP generates a lot of stuff (online and offline local database modes that sync automatically) I wouldn't know what to post lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downloaded the [SUP 101 - BlackBerry Project](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/bpx/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/206cab4d-5358-2e10-7fbf-f0d8e1f79276) and checked the sources.

It does not contain networking code in the form a usual BB app would do.

However I see the `SUP101.SUP101DB` class has the following method:

```
private static String getSyncTransportSuffix() {
    com.sybase.persistence.ConnectionProfile syncProfile = 
        getSynchronizationProfile();
    return com.sybase.afx.util.NetworkUtil.getTransportUrlSuffix(syncProfile);
}
```

So the code uses `com.sybase.afx.util.NetworkUtil` to get url suffix. By appending such suffix to a url we say to the underlaying BB API what network transport to use. Unfortunatelly sources do not contain `com.sybase.afx.util.NetworkUtil` to look how exactly it works.

I should say that even with native Java BB development detecting a proper network transport may turn to be a very tricky part. OS 5+ provides a new networking API that is much better, but for the older OS it is hard. This SUP project is built with BlackBerry JRE 4.6.1, so it can not use new OS 5+ networking API. Who knows maybe SUP simply fails to detect proper network transport?

Any way, just a few ideas to try:

- check for APN settings on the device, sometimes they have to be populated in order to use Direct TCP transport (it depends on wireless provider requirements). APN name/pass are wireless provider specific. Usually googling allows to find proper APN settings for a provider.
- if your device has WiFi try enabling it. SUP should be smart enough to prefer WiFi if available. In this case I assume networking should have no issues.

Comment: I just enabled APN because the UltraLiteJ lib was complaining about it but we only have test devices that don't have a sim so we don't have the APN. I am working with the Wifi on a local network, I checked I could ping the device from the same machine as the server

Comment: Got to the solution thanks to your comments ^^ (I added a section in my post for those who have the same problem)

Comment: Jason, I'm glad I was helpful. Actually you should have posted your solution as an answer and accept it, because my answer is not the solution.

Comment: If I had found it on my own I would have, but I didn't even know where to start looking for look for, you can copy the solution in you answer if you want